# How to hide the part of rectange inside the svg image using css

Tags: css

I want to hide the top part of rectangle inside the svg image. How it can be done? 
I tried using absolute I am not getting expected result. I have made two svg image as absolute now I want to make hide top most part of rectangle inside the circle svg image.

Expected Result should be like this:

[image]

I am getting like this:

[image]

HTML Code:

```
<div class="customer">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-3">
              <div class="types">
                <div class="term">
                  <h3>Term Insurance</h3>
                </div>
                <img src="abc.svg" alt="">
              </div>
              </div>
            </div> 
            </div>
          </div>
          </div>
        </div>

CSS Code:




.customer {
    height: 200px;
    padding: 30px 0;
}
    .types {
        margin-left: 100px;
    }
    .types img {
        position: absolute;
        top: 113px;
        left: 218px;
    }
    .types::before {
        display: block;
        content: '';
        background: url('dotted.svg');
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        height: 250px;
        width: 260px;
        overflow: hidden;

    }
    .types::after {
        content: '';
        width: 250px;
        height: 478px;
        border-radius: 17px;
        box-shadow: 0 3px 6px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16);
        background-color: #ffffff;
        position: absolute;

    }
    .term {
        width: 259px;
        height: 102px;
        position: absolute;
    }
    .term h3 {
        font-size: 36px;
        line-height: 1;
        position: absolute;
        top: -232px;
        left: 45px;
    }
```

Comment: Please indent your code properly

Comment: where is your SVG file?

Answer (score 0):

If the image is `position: absolute`, you can pull the image down with `margin-bottom: -100px` for example